# Laravel Application takes over 2s to boot any page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-8

I have created a few Laravel applications but this is my first Laravel 8 / PHP 8 application.

The issue I am having is that every single page and request takes over 2 seconds to load, whether it be an API call or loading a page (this is also the case for just loading a blank page and echoing 'hello').

I have added caching through Redis, optimized the application and any queries as much as I can but they don't seem to make a difference.

It's really throwing me off why even a blank page is taking more than 2s to load.

I have looked at the network tab on Developer tools and it's the document that takes a while to load and in the waterfall section it's the time to first byte which is taking the longest - the rest are milliseconds.

[image: Image of Chrome Network Tab]

Comment: Is this problem on your local environment? If yes, does any other Laravel application on your system facing the same issues when you run them now

Comment: Hi @Dennis I have 4/5 local applications using the same setup and none of them suffer from the same loading issue.

Comment: comment out our service providers (in config/app.php) one by one to see if you can find a culprit

Comment: @apokryfos Will try this now. Will get back to you, thanks

Comment: @apokryfos I commented them out 1 by 1, some gave errors about target class could not be found but when they errored the time came down to ~300ms. But obviously I can't remove these as the application won't work

Comment: Hi @TaylorStocks, good to know the other projects are working fine. What apokryfos said is a way to track down the "big boys" in your project. A clean laravel project is fast as it is, so the default providers will not causing the problem. Continuing on the tip of apokryfos; do you have any custom service providers? 

One other tip to do: Create a new laravel 8.x project with PHP 8 in another folder and without changing anything, open the project and see what happens. It could be something with PHP 8 on your local machine, what local server are you using? E.g. Xampp/Mamp/Valet

Comment: @Dennis I don't have any custom providers but will definitely give the new app a try. I might also try pushing to a live environment to see if it's just my local

Comment: @TaylorStocks And what do you use for local development? I know that Xampp (MacOs) is very slow. I'm using Laravel Valet and its just fast (compared to Xampp)

Comment: So the culprits usually are service providers either yours (laravel ships with a few by default) or ones that belong to packages you are using. Other culprits are also middleware. You need to narrow down where the slowdown is coming from because in a clean Laravel project there are no such slowdowns

Comment: are you having this problem with static resources too? how about if you request an 'jpeg' image?

Comment: I have this issue with every single dom request that is made. If I go to a blank get route with nothing being called other than middleware and headers I still get the slow load time

Answer (score 1):

As you tell, you have many applications running on your setup. But you can have lower time on boot with few methods :

```
php artisan optimize or php artisan optimize --force
```

You can precompile the assets using

```
php artisan optimize

php artisan config:cache

php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: Hi @Raphael, I constantly run optimize and clear the caching on my project. This never makes a difference. Thanks